# Handling values above 0x7F using String.parseByte(string s) - Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

My Java code scans strings from an external file to populate a byte array in a data structure.

In particular, I need to scan a two character string then allocate a byte containing the literal values in the string (e.g. "3A" to 0x3A).  My range for these values can be anywhere between[ 0x00, 0xFF ].

Does anyone know a work around?

Thank you,

-Using the Byte.parseByte(string a) method only works for values less than Byte.MAX(0x7F), else my code generates a "NumberFormatException: Value out of Range."
-Using bit manipulation have only generated garbage because without a conversion I am just shifting ascii values.

-Trying to parse any primitive greater than a byte also generates a NumberFormatException.

```java
    ...
    String a;
    byte b;
    Scanner fr = new Scanner(pfile);

    fr.useDelimiter(" :|\\n");

        while(fr.hasNext()){
            a = fr.next();
            if(a.charAt(0) != ' ' && a.charAt(0) != '-'){
                //d = Long.parseLong(a);
                b = Byte.parseByte(a.trim(), 16);
                System.out.println("String a : " + a + " Parsed byte: " +   b);
            }
        }
    fr.close();
```

Comment: You can't store any number larger than 127 (0x7F) in a Byte, by definition. A signed byte doesn't physically have enough bits to hold higher values. You'll have to use a ```short``` or ```int```. Any value over ```0x7F``` isn't actually a byte as far as java is concerned,although with some languages it could be stored in an unsigned byte. Java isn't one of them.

Comment: If all you're concerned about is the bit pattern then `byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt(a, 16);` will work. If you need something else then I suggest you explain better.

Comment: @JamesKPolk.  Thank you.  Changing the code to byte b = (byte)Integer.parseInt(a.trim(), 16);  lets me parse larger values that keep the bit pattern (e.g. String a = 3A ...  Parsed byte = 58(decimal)).  I am new to programming and sorry about the obvious typo.